# C - Print a specific Trie segment

Tags: c, trie

a while back I asked what I should use to store a lot of product codes.
I decided to use Tries, and I made this code, which I upload to my Github repository

https://github.com/OctavioMaia/Projetos

But now I have to print my Trie according to my project, but I'm not being able to do it.

I also need to print, e.g: all codes started with the char 'A' alphabetically , so my print function needs to recieve a trie and a char to print.

The problem is I'm not being able to succesfully print it. I'm not experienced with pointers, so this is even harder for me

I hope you can help me out.

The code is documented in portuguese but I can explain it for you guys.

- It reads the product codes from the txt.
- Removes the \n using the strtok and saves it to the trie.
- Now I should print all the codes started by, e.g: A, alphabetically

Comment: I decided to try an AVL tree but I'm having some problems storing the elements into the AVL.
It reaches 6471 out of the 195534 codes it needs to insert.
Any idea why this might happen? Heres my code

http://pastebin.com/v6kgQEiw
http://pastebin.com/7xDgmes8

And here is what im trying to process into the AVL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OctavioMaia/Projetos/master/FichProdutos.txt

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a stack (last in, first out) data structure containing a node pointer an integer, which is where you'll store your index variable.

As you move down your trie, push the current node pointer and index onto the stack, move on to the corresponding node and reset the index variable to 0.

When you get to an end, perform which-ever action you intend to perform on the current node, pop a node pointer and index from your stack increment the index.

When there are no more nodes to push or pop, your job is done.